# Div only visible with something in it

Tags: html, css, invisible

I am currently working on a project and have bounced into a problem. I currently have an "outer", a "middle" and an "inner" div so I can place my content exactly in the middle. But when I place a div inside the "inner" div the "inner" div is visible but not the one inside(if it doesn't contain something like a letter).

Here is an example:

```css
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
}

.invisiblediv {
    height 30px;
    width: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html> 
        
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="example.css">
        </head>
        
        <body>
          
            <div class="outer">
            <div class="middle">
            <div class="inner">
              
                <div class="invisiblediv"></div>
            
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
        </body>
        
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you have an error in your CSS. In `invisiblediv` CSS, after the attribute `height` a colon is missing. Thus the `div` is rendered with height 0.

Comment: that is not semi-colon it's colon

Answer (score 1):

Add colon after height

```
 .invisiblediv {
    height : 30px;
    width: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://output.jsbin.com/pinimocino/2/